# Подстановка ID текущего раздела в шаблон WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Новичок в php!
Имеются одинаковые шаблоны для нескольких страниц-слагов (page-cat1, page-cat2...), которые отличаются лишь значением ID категории выводимых на ней материалов. То есть отличие шаблонов только в `'category' => NN`:

```html
<?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10 , 'category' => NN, 'orderby' => 'date'); ?>
```

Категории материалов имеют те же имена-слаги: cat1, cat2... И хочется сделать один универсальный шаблон для страниц, чтобы переменная ID категории материалов (а лучше имя) передавалось из слага страниц: cat1, cat2...

WP-Kama дал подсказку задействовать `$cat_id = get_query_var( 'cat' );` или `$cat_name = get_query_var( 'category_name' );`, но как подключить ее к значению `'category' => NN`, не хватает знаний

Comment: В целом, дублирование вывода записей из категорий на шаблоны страниц, это немножко велосипед. Если я все верно понял и Вы выводите записи из категорий на страницы, то это `get_query_var('cat')` конечно же не будет работать, так как в данный момент Вы находитесь на странице, а не категории. Можете получать слаг страницы при помощи `global $post; $page_slug = $post->post_name;` или `$page_slug = get_post_field('post_name', get_the_ID);` и потом подставить его сюда `'category' => $page_slug` если слаги прям совпадают.

Comment: Смог получить искомое имя слага страницы через `$page_slug = get_query_var('name'); echo $page_slug` Но преобразовать его в ID категории и подставить в массив аргументов не выходит. Попробовал `$page_slug->ID`, `get_queried_object_id()->ID`

Comment: Замените `category`, на `category_name` если хотите подставить туда слаг, если хотите подставить `ID`, то используйте `cat`.

Comment: Ура, заработало: `<?php $slug_name = get_query_var('name'); ?>
<?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10 , 'category_name' => $slug_name , 'orderby' => 'date' ); ?>`

Comment: Как поблагодарить и закрыть вопрос?

Comment: Для закрытия возможно есть кнопка удаления, не уверен